# pig latin issues with output code for python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble with the code only producing the first two letters of the first word and then attaching the 'AY' to the end while it runs. I can't seem to figure out how to correct this error.

```
def main():
      strin = input('Enter a sentence (English): ')
      strlist = strin.split()
      i = 0
      pigsen = ''
      while i < len(strlist):
          word = strlist[i]
          j = 1
          fc = word[0].upper()
          pigword =''
          while j < len(word):
              pigword += word[j].upper()
              j += 1
              pigword += fc + 'AY'
              pigsen += pigword + ' '
              i +=1
      print('Pig Latin: ' +str(pigsen))
main()
```

Comment: Learn to use a Python source debugger and step through the code.  The errors will easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume this is just the start of a pig Latin generator and you'll add the other rules (at least a couple more) once you get this much working.  Second, let's simplify the code as a way of fixing it:

```
def main():
    sentence = input('Enter a sentence (English): ')

    words = sentence.upper().split()

    latin_words = []

    for word in words:

        first, rest = word[0], word[1:]

        latin_word = rest + first + 'AY'

        latin_words.append(latin_word)

    print('Pig Latin:', *latin_words)

main()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py 
Enter a sentence (English): He complimented me on my English
Pig Latin: EHAY OMPLIMENTEDCAY EMAY NOAY YMAY NGLISHEAY
>
```

I would say the problem with your code is you made it too complicated.